# change file extension with a ruby script

Tags: ruby, bash, shell

I'm trying to change the exstension of a file passing the arguments by console

```
system = "rename" , "'s/\#{ARGV[0]}$/\#{ARGV[1]}'", "*#{ARGV[1]}"
```

The code is correct because it works on console but when I put it in a script I have trouble with

```
s/\#
```

because it appears in pink and the console does not get it.

Comment: _"because it appears in pink"_ – what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

1. you don't want to send literal single quotes, so remove them.
2. you want to remove the backslashes so you let Ruby evaluate those expressions.
3. you're missing the trailing slash.
4. what's that equal sign doing?
5. did you want `ARGV[0]` in the last argument to rename, instead of ARGV[1]?
6. you want to use `*` wildcard, which requires a shell to expand into a list of files, which means you can't use the list form of `system`

Try

```
system "/usr/bin/rename -n 's/#{ARGV[0]}$/#{ARGV[1]}/' *#{ARGV[0]}"
```

Remove the `-n` option if it looks like you're going to rename the way you want.

---

And, of course, you don't need to call out to the shell for this:

```
Dir.glob("*#{ARGV[0]}").each {|fname| 
    newname = fname.sub(/#{ARGV[0]}$/, ARGV[1])
    File.rename(fname, newname)
}
```